# Process multiple files and append them in linux/unix

Tags: linux, awk, cat

I have over 100 files with at least 5-8 columns (tab-separated) in each file. I need to extract first three columns from each file and add fourth column with some predefined text and append them.

Let's say I have 3 files: `file001.txt`, `file002.txt`, `file003.txt`.

`file001.txt`:

```
chr1 1 2 15
chr2 3 4 17
```

`file002.txt`:

```
chr1 1 2 15
chr2 3 4 17
```

`file003.txt`:

```
chr1 1 2 15
chr2 3 4 17
```

`combined_file.txt`:

```
chr1 1 2 f1
chr2 3 4 f1
chr1 1 2 f2
chr2 3 4 f2
chr1 1 2 f3
chr2 3 4 f3
```

For simplicity I kept file contents same. 
My script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..3}; do
j=$(printf '%03d' $i)
awk 'BEGIN { OFS="\t"}; {print $1,$2,$3}' file${j}.txt | awk -v k="$j" 'BEGIN {print $0"\t$k”}' | cat >> combined_file.txt
done
```

But the script is giving the following errors:

awk: non-terminated string  $k”}... at source line 1
 context is

> > > <<< 
> > >       awk: giving up
> > >        source line number 2
> > >       awk: non-terminated string  $k”}... at source line 1
> > >        context is
> > >        <<< 
> > >       awk: giving up
> > >        source line number 2

Can some one help me to figure it out?

Comment: You have a problem statement, and coupled with that you have a bash script solving (what I assume) are parts of your problem. Where are you stuck? I'm missing a question. It is also confusing with your file00<n>.txt, where all of them have the exact same content.

Comment: @mattias, post is edited.

Comment: You have mixed some special characters here. Notice the difference between " and ” in your BEGIN statement `'BEGIN {print $0"\t$k”}'`. That should get you out of that error you're getting. But then you probably have other issues with the awk command.

Comment: @mattias, Thanks. It is working now but printing the fourth column as $k instead of its value.

Comment: use echo $k instead of BEGIN {print $0"\t$k”}

Comment: @aguertin, can you be specific, you want to replace BEGIN {print $0"\t$k”} with echo $k inside awk?

Comment: @ aguertin, Nope. Its not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need two different `awk` scripts. And you don't use `$` to refer to variables in `awk`, that's used to refer to input fields (i.e. `$k` means access the field whose number is in the variable `k`).

```
for i in {1..3}; do
    j=$(printf '%03d' $i)
    awk -v k="$j" -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, $2, $3, k}' file$j.txt
done > combined_file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. It works fine. I just added k into the print.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments your problem is youre trying to use odd characters as if they were double quotes. Once you fix that though, you don't need a loop or any of that other complexity all you need is:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {$NF="f"ARGIND} 1' file*
chr1    1       2       f1
chr2    3       4       f1
chr1    1       2       f2
chr2    3       4       f2
chr1    1       2       f3
chr2    3       4       f3
```

The above used GNU awk for ARGIND.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain the details.

Comment: Sure - what part do you not understand? If you just want to start learning awk, I highly recommend the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.